# Unable to modify a text file in a REST Web service

Tags: java, rest

My program implements a method X of a REST web service that calls another method Y in another class. The latter modifies a line in a text file.

I have tested method Y without using the REST method X and everything went well and the file was changed. But when I call the PUT method X, the file is not changed.

The Java method of the web service is as follows:

```
public String reduceEnergyConsumption(int id, String action) {
        String ch;
        int nb;
        if (action=="reduce")
            AQSensor.setState(id,"Off"); 
        else
            AQSensor.setState(id,"On");

        return action;
}
```

AQSensor is:

```
static AirQualitySensorManager AQSensor= new AirQualitySensorManagerImp();
```

The setSate (id, state) method is as follows:

```
public void setState(int id, String state) {
        Vector<String> VInter= new Vector<String>();
        try {
            InputStream ips = new FileInputStream("stateAQS.txt");
            InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(ips);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ipsr);
            String ligne;
            int i=0;
            while ((ligne = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                i++;   
                VInter.add(ligne);
            }
            VInter.setElementAt(state, id);
    //****move the vector in the file
            OutputStream ops = new FileOutputStream("stateAQS.txt");
            OutputStreamWriter opsw = new OutputStreamWriter(ops);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(opsw);
            for(int e=0;e<VInter.size();e++){
                bw.append(VInter.elementAt(e));
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The calling code in the client is as follows:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter the action: ");
String action = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("enter the index: ");
String pr= sc.nextLine();

Entity<String> userEntity = Entity.entity(action, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
Response response = target.path("aqsensor").path("reduceEnergy/"+pr+"/"+action).request().put(userEntity);

System.out.println("response is: "+response.getStatus());
```

Now when I run this, it shows me the following:

```
enter the action:
rise
enter the index:
5
response is: 200
```

So 200 Ok. But the file line was not changed. Where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you close all your streams at the end of modifying them?

Comment: yes, I close its.

Comment: Please try catching all exceptions, not only IOExceptions and see what happens. Please check the network traffic log and see if everything is ok.

Comment: Please step through your server code using a debugger or by printing lines to a log file and check if the correct lines are passed to bw.append().

Comment: I catching all exceptions, it shows me as follows:  java.io.FileNotFoundException: stateAQS.txt (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't specify the full file path. Because you specify only the file name, the application searches the file in the current directory. When you call the REST API method, the current directory is not the directory where the file is located and the method cannot find the file.

You can solve your problem by specifying a full path name as a parameter of `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: also be sure that your file is relative to the ressource folder the better is to get ressource as current directory then adding your relative ressource path using the getRessource(".").getpath